# Elastic mapreduce cluster always in this status: Provisioning Amazon EC2 capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, amazon-vpc

When I create an elastic mapreducer cluster, within a created vpc, is always showing this message:

```
Provisioning Amazon EC2 capacity
```

After more than 30 minutes I get an error:

```
Failed to start the job flow due to an internal error
```

Im trying to find where the issue is but without sucess, so I came here to ask to see if you can help me.

I will explain all the steps that I did to create the vpc and subnets that Im using in my elasticmapreducer cluster:

1º Create VPC:

```
Name Tag: elasticVPC
CIDR block: 10.0.0.0/16
Tenancy: Default
```

2º Create Subnets (one in each Availability Zone):

```
Name Tag: subnet1
VPC: elasticVPC
Availability Zone:  us-east-1b
CIDR BLOCK: 10.0.0.0/24

Name Tag: subnet2
VPC: elasticVPC
Availability Zone:  us-east-1c
CIDR BLOCK: 10.0.1.0/24

Name Tag: subnet3
VPC: elasticVPC
Availability Zone:  us-east-1d
CIDR BLOCK: 10.0.2.0/24

Name Tag: subnet4
VPC: elasticVPC
Availability Zone:  us-east-1e
CIDR BLOCK: 10.0.4.0/24
```

3º Create Route Table
    Name Tag: elasticRT
    VPC: elasticVPC

4º Create Internet Gateway
    Name Tag: elasticIG
    Attach this IG to VPC elasticVPC

5º Route tables -> routes -> edit -> add another route
    Destination: 0.0.0.0/0
    Target: igw...(elasticIG)

6º Route tables -> subnet associations -> select all subnets to associate

Then to create the elastic mapreducer cluster:

In Network I selected the created vpc, and in EC2 Subnet I selected one created subnet.

In Steps, I selected StreamingStep, selected the mapper, reducer, input and output and then I create in create cluster.

And I have always "Provisioning Amazon EC2 capacity"

Comment: Are you using Spot pricing? If so, try it without to see if that removes the error.

Comment: EMR might fail to launch if it has no Internet access (used to download software and configure the server). Are you able to launch a normal Amazon EC2 instance in that subnet, and connect to it?